# Basic auth with isomorphic-fetch

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-redux, fetch-api, isomorphic-fetch-api

I want to do a post request passing some credentials using isomorphic-fetch. Here is the code I have for now:

```
export default function fetchJson(url: string, options: any) {
  options.headers = (<any>Object).assign({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }, options.headers);
  return fetch(url, options)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON);
}

export function fetchLogs(dispatch_ok: any, dispatch_error: any) {
      var URL = "http://server_address:8080/api/getlogs/";
      return fetchJson(URL, {
                       method: 'get',
                       credentials: 'include',
                       headers: {
                            Authorization: 'Basic '+window.btoa('user:passwd'),
                       }
             }).then((data: any) => {
                 if (data.results.length != 0) {
                     dispatch_ok(data.results);
                 } else {
                     dispatch_error("No logs could be retrieved");
                 }
             }).catch((error: any) => {
                 dispatch_error(error.message);
             });
}
```

This code does not work as it redirects to the login page. Any idea on how to make this work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basic auth with isomorphic-fetch

The code you have will fine. i.e. it will post the authorization header just fine.

## More

The redirecting logic is most likely broken.

Comment: Any idea on how I could debug this ?